# I downloaded a game to my console. When I open it, it gave me this error: "This disc's region code is wrong for this console." What should I do?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network, region-lock

[image]
I bought Sonic Unleashed from Xbox Store and it gives me this error. I am a student so I can't buy a new console. As this game is digital, I don't know the region code.I live in Turkey and we use Pal here. What should I do?

Comment: Contact support through the link they give you?

Comment: I think this is Xbox 360 and not Xbox One (I switched the tags).  Based off the UI, and the fact that Sonic Unleased is not out for Xbox One.

Comment: I tried to contact them and the tech crew is working on it. But I wanted to learn if you had a solution or not. And yes, it is on Xbox 360

Comment: now you can change your region if you'd like, but that might actually cause so other issues for other games.  https://support.xbox.com/en-US/my-account/microsoft-account/update-microsoft-account-country-region